# family of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a bounded region in complex plane . Let $\{f_n\}$ be sequence of analytic functions on $G$ that are continuous on the closure of $G$

Assume that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on boundary of $G$. Prove that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ on $G$.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Please provide more context to your questions, instead of just copying them from your textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: maximum modulus principle (applied to $f_n-f$).

Comment: I tried to use maximum modulus principle but I could not figure out. could you please go little bit more

Comment: @Ganga why didn't you write that in your original question then, instead of having *us* guess what you already tried?